# How to optimize External Storage file search on Android

Tags: android, file, path, android-sdcard, dir

**Requirement**

Scan all folders and files on external storage to find all apk files and for each apk file, get info and display progress.

**How I did it so far**

My initial thought is that this is a simple thing to achieve. But well... even it it sort of works, it does not perform as expected.

I use an AsyncTask to perform the scanning in background. Here is how I do:

```
 private ArrayList<String> sdcardAppsPath;

  protected class ScanTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Scanner, ArrayList<Apk>> {
     private ArrayList<Apk> sdcardApps;  
    @Override
        protected ArrayList<App> doInBackground(Context... params) {

            visitAllDirsAndFiles(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
            for (String path : sdcardAppsPath) {
                //get info about apk file and
                publishProgress(values)  //show in some textviews number of files scanned, total files
                sdcardApps.add(currentScannedItemFoundInfo);
            }
          return sdcardApps
    }

    @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Scanner... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
           // update some textView texts based on values
       }   
    }
```

And

```
  // Process all files and directories under dir
        public void visitAllDirsAndFiles(File dir) {
            if (dir != null) {
                if (dir.getAbsoluteFile().toString().endsWith(".apk")) {
                    sdcardAppsPath.add(dir.getAbsoluteFile().toString());
                }

                if (dir.isDirectory()) {
                    String[] children = dir.list();
                    if (children != null) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                            visitAllDirsAndFiles(new File(dir, children[i]));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

As you can see after `vistitAllDirsAndFiles` I get an `ArrayList<String>` with all apk files I need, so I can check for each what I want. The downside is that it might take a lot of time to build this `sdcardAppsPath` if there are many files on the card and the app shows no progress while the paths are being found.

**What I want to achieve**

I want to be able in the `doInBackground` to somehow for each found file, get the info I need, update progress and then continue with scanning. Any ideas how to update my code to work like this ?

Comment: Is this the complete code listing? Don't you need an `onProgressUpdate`?

Comment: no relevant parts onProgressUpdate...

Comment: Actually, now that I look at it more closely, shouldn't you be calling `publishProgress` in your `visitAllDirsAndFiles` method if you want to update progress while searching for files?

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you would want to call `publishProgress` inside your `visitAllDirsAndFiles` method if you want to update progress while searching for files, instead of iterating through the list afterwards and calling it then...